# Help deleting someone else's Google account from my phone

Tags: google-account

My boyfriend's Google account was added onto my phone. How do I delete it from my phone and if I do, will it also be deleted on his phone?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Account > Google then select the account to be removed.

No, deleting an account from a device only remove it in that device.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just go to the Settings app >> Account >> Google. Then, select the account that you want to remove. Click on it. Done.

Of course, No. This process only remove an account from that devices.

Finally, click on the Add Account button and enter your account to login.